# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ? Resource issue

Tags: javascript, html

My login page requires login.js to load but upon checking the console on Chrome it shows that its not loaded. How can I fix this?

my login page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Login</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="r/img/favicon.png" type="image/png" />

<link href="r/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="r/css/flat-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="r/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="r/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="r/js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="r/js/login.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
<div class="row navbar navbar-inverse login_block">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p id="login_response">&nbsp;</p>
        <p><input id="field1" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Login or Login:password" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" /></p>
        <p><input id="field2" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" required="required" /></p>
        <p>
            <button id="login_button" type="button" onclick="log_in()" class="btn btn-info">Log in</button>
            <img id="loader" src="r/img/loader.gif" alt="" />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This question is going to need more context. At least how you are attempting to view this page. Are you just loading this HTML file from your system storage? What is the file tree/structure for your project?

Comment: I'm viewing on browser. The site is on my VPS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like other js file as the same question:

```
<script src="r/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="r/js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="r/js/login.js"></script>
```

did they are loaded successfully?
If not, you can check the server static file access permission.
Else, check login.js file path(r/js/login.js) is right on the server.